# How to apply pulse effect on SCNSphere object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios10, scenekit

I want to apply pulse effect on SCNSphere object, can any one help me for this.

[Pulse effect](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ddec8ff304ce4e553636bec650c053eefc0069f1/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f3251305830353270326d3337316d3077324f30432f68616c6f6769662e676966)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't even know what the pulse effect is.

Comment: Attached is the reference link of that effect.  https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ddec8ff304ce4e553636bec650c053eefc0069f1/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f3251305830353270326d3337316d3077324f30432f68616c6f6769662e676966

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was after a similar effect (see below) in one of my apps and used a SceneKit shader modifier.

[image: Pulse effect in SceneKit]

Here's some example code that may help.

```
 let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0))
 boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
 scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

 let pulseSize:CGFloat = 5.0
 let pulsePlane = SCNPlane(width: pulseSize, height: pulseSize)
 pulsePlane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
 pulsePlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
 let pulseNode = SCNNode(geometry: pulsePlane)

 let pulseShaderModifier =
 "#pragma transparent; \n" +
 "vec4 originalColour = _surface.diffuse; \n" +
 "vec4 transformed_position = u_inverseModelTransform * u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0); \n" +
 "vec2 xy = vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y); \n" +
 "float xyLength = length(xy); \n" +
 "float xyLengthNormalised = xyLength/" + String(describing: pulseSize / 2) + "; \n" +
 "float speedFactor = 1.5; \n" +
 "float maxDist = fmod(u_time, speedFactor) / speedFactor; \n" +
 "float distbasedalpha = step(maxDist, xyLengthNormalised); \n" +
 "distbasedalpha = max(distbasedalpha, maxDist); \n" +
 "_surface.diffuse = mix(originalColour, vec4(0.0), distbasedalpha);"

 pulsePlane.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.surface:pulseShaderModifier]
 boxNode.addChildNode(pulseNode)
```

The red box (`boxNode`) is included for context only.

The pulse node consists of a `SCNPlane`, for which the fragment shader is modified via SceneKit's surface shader modifier. If you comment out the code that sets the shader modifier you'll see a flat blue square as expected.

The code specified for the surface entry point of a shader modifier is injected into the fragment shader SceneKit uses. This means you're working in screen space with pixels. The first few lines of the shader modifier translate the screen space coords back to the model space coordinates using the inverse model and view transforms.

Each rendered pixels distance to the centre of the plane (in model space) is calculated `xyLength`. This is then normalised for the total size of the 'pulse plane' `xyLengthNormalised`. A modulo operation on time is used to get the pulsing effect; you could switch this to a `sin` function to get an in-then-out type pulsing. We use the result of the mod operation to determine what pixels should be transparent.

The plane spins with the red box as it's a child node of the box. You can override this behaviour by adding a constraint as shown below. I've used a look at constraint as I've never personally had much success with the `SCNBillboardConstraint`.

```
let pulseNodeConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraNode)
pulseNode.constraints = [pulseNodeConstraint]
```

End result

[image: Pulse effect in SceneKit with constraint]

For those who prefer Objective-C...

```
SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0 length:1.0 chamferRadius:0.0]];
boxNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];

CGFloat pulseSize = 5.0;
SCNPlane *pulsePlane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:pulseSize height:pulseSize];
[pulsePlane.firstMaterial setDoubleSided:true];
pulsePlane.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor blueColor];
SCNNode *pulseNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:pulsePlane];

NSString *pulseShaderModifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"#pragma transparent; \n"
"vec4 originalColour = _surface.diffuse; \n"
"vec4 transformed_position = u_inverseModelTransform * u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0); \n"
"vec2 xy = vec2(transformed_position.x, transformed_position.y); \n"
"float xyLength = length(xy); \n"
"float xyLengthNormalised = xyLength/%f; \n"
"float speedFactor = 1.5; \n"
"float maxDist = fmod(u_time, speedFactor) / speedFactor; \n"
"float distbasedalpha = step(maxDist, xyLengthNormalised); \n"
"distbasedalpha = max(distbasedalpha, maxDist); \n"
"_surface.diffuse = mix(originalColour, vec4(0.0), distbasedalpha);", pulseSize/2.0];

NSDictionary *smdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pulseShaderModifier forKey:SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface];
[pulsePlane.firstMaterial setShaderModifiers:smdict];

[boxNode addChildNode:pulseNode];

SCNLookAtConstraint *pulseNodeConstraint = [SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:cameraNode];
NSArray *constraints = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pulseNodeConstraint];
[pulseNode setConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: Thanks lock for the help... But i have no experience in swift, i was tried to convert your code in Objective C but can't succeed. Can you please help me for resolve this. it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Sure, ObjC code example included above. Good chance to brush up on my Objective-C before I forget what it looks like ;-) . [Full source code link](https://gist.github.com/lachlanhurst/0d0f9f79868cbd0e7053cde62ab22822)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I am trying with your code but pulse effect is not working, can you please help us for this.

Comment: It gives warnings in console while i am applying pulseShaderModifier object for shadow/pulse effect.

Comment: Which device are you trying to run on? The above was tested on a iPhone7, this will default to using Metal for rendering. Older phones/the simulator will use OpenGL for rendering, this could cause some issues.

Comment: I am trying in simulator iPhone 6s - iOS 10.2(14C89)

Comment: Try changing the `fmod` function call in the shader modifier to just `mod`. Just tested in the simulator, and this seems to fix it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Hi Lock, Is it possible to create same pulse effect like default map application? Here is the demo link for the same : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5149ajnd9y64uz3/Userlocation.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use pod from https://github.com/shu223/Pulsator

**Configure**

```
let pulsator = Pulsator()
view.layer.addSublayer(pulsator)
pulsator.start()
```

**Number of Pulses**

```
pulsator.numPulse = 3
```

**Radius**

```
pulsator.radius = 240.0
```

**Color**

```
pulsator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

**Animation Duration**

Use following properties

```
animationDuration : duration for each pulse
pulseInterval : interval between pulses
```

**Easing**

You can set the `timingFunction` property.

**Repeat**

Use `repeatCount` property.

Just configured it properly. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Hasya for response.. but i want to apply pulse effect in SCNSphere(Scenekit) object?

Comment: Did you tried integrating pulse on SCNSphere? It will work, try out once.

Comment: Yes i tried its works like flashing not give effect like pulse.  Here is my code which i am using :     CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
        theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        theAnimation.duration=1.0;
        theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
        theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
        theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
        [objSphereNode addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];

Comment: Can you please post your code in your question. Just edit your question, So anyone can look into same and help you asap.